# Getting passwords error on Helm upgrade for Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am getting the following error on installing a custom docker image as a revision. I am not able to figure out the reason. So far I have tried adding secrets with the password and it didn't work

```
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -n airflow -f values.yaml --debug
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release airflow
upgrade.go:144: [debug] preparing upgrade for airflow
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: execution error at (airflow/charts/postgresql/templates/secrets.yaml:20:15): 
PASSWORDS ERROR: The secret "airflow-postgresql" does not contain the key "password"
```

Comment: How are you adding you password?

Comment: `kubectl create secret generic airflow-postgresql --dry-run=client -o yaml |      yq e '.data.password="<password>" - |      kubectl apply -f -` - This is the command I used

Comment: @GaiusGD'cruz can you write an answer if you got this working please? Your command has a hanging `'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
kubectl create secret generic airflow-postgresql -n airflow --from-literal=password='postgres' --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

I think the error is due to the helm create the airflow-postgresql's secrets using "postgres-password" as the key while the helm update expects "password" as the key.

Or:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/release_notes.html#airflow-helm-chart-1-8-0-2023-02-06

Airflow Helm Chart 1.8.0 (2023-02-06)
Significant Changes
bitnami/postgresql subchart updated to 12.1.9 (#29071)
The version of postgresql installed is still version 11.

If you are upgrading an existing helm release with the built-in postgres database, you will either need to delete your release and reinstall fresh, or manually delete these 2 objects:

```
kubectl delete secret {RELEASE_NAME}-postgresql
kubectl delete statefulset {RELEASE_NAME}-postgresql
```

As a reminder, it is recommended to set up an external database in production.

This version of the chart uses different variable names for setting usernames and passwords in the postgres database.

postgresql.auth.enablePostgresUser is used to determine if the “postgres” admin account will be created.

postgresql.auth.postgresPassword sets the password for the “postgres” user.

postgresql.auth.username and postrgesql.auth.password are used to set credentials for a non-admin account if desired.

postgresql.postgresqlUsername and postgresql.postresqlPassword, which were used in the previous version of the chart, are no longer used.

Users will need to make those changes in their values files if they are changing the Postgres configuration.

Previously the subchart version was 10.5.3.